# Why do we need ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

Angular apps use the `ng-click()` attribute rather than the the `onclick` event.

Why is this?

Comment: So you can allow users to click on disabled elements, apparently. (This is something `ng-click` allows. Why this should be so, I have no idea.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

ng-click holds an angular expression.  Angular expressions are evaluated in the context of an Angular [scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), which is bound to the element having the ng-click attribute or an ancestor of that element.

The Angular expression language doesn't include flow control statements and can't declare variables or define functions.  These limitations mean templates can only access variables and run functions made available by a controller or directive.

Answer (score 114):

Angular doesn't change the meaning of the `onclick` attribute; it adds the parallel `ng-click` attribute to take an [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). `onclick` takes plain old JavaScript code even when you're using Angular.

Practically speaking, suppose what you're doing in a click handler is changing some variables in an Angular scope, or calling a function in an Angular scope that changes some variables.
To do that from JavaScript code (like what you would put in `onclick`) requires a bunch of steps

- get a reference to the scope
- assign the variable or call the function
- call `scope.$apply` so that anything watching for updates to the variables that you changed gets notified

This looks like:

```
<a onclick="var $scope = angular.element(event.target).scope(); $scope.yourVar = 42; $scope.$apply()">Go</a>
```

and with `ng-click` and an Angular expression for the assignment, almost all of that is implicit:

```
<a ng-click="yourVar = 42">Go</a>
```