# when $digest cycle is called?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm very confused when a digest cycle is happening, is it called periodically based on a timer every 50ms (as it says [here](http://blog.bguiz.com/post/60397801810/digest-cycles-in-single-page-apps) and implied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs)) or is it called after every event that enters the angular context (as it says [here](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634666/how-does-angularjss-watch-function-work/18639070#18639070) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463902/how-does-the-binding-and-digesting-work-in-angularjs/12491335#12491335)) ?

Example when it is matter:

In my model, I have a variable called `myVar` with the value of 3.
In my HTML, I have `{{myvar}}`.
An event such as a button click is fired and raises a handler in the controller, the code inside the handler is:

```
$scope.myVar = 4;
// some heavy actions takes place for 3 seconds...
$scope.myVar = 5;
```

Assuming the UI thread is not blocked, what will the user see after the button click? will he see only 5 or will he see 4 and after 3 seconds 5?

Comment: The digest cycle happens periodically. You can prove this to yourself by using Chrome and making a profile recording. View it with the flame chart and you will see the digest cycles happening.

Comment: @aet then why is it also called after some events? it is unnecessary

Comment: You are asking why so many people feel the need to manually trigger digest cycles and use things like $scope.$apply()? In a lot of cases they probably do not need to and it is a symptom of a larger/different problem. It is necessary sometimes to do so, when things "outside" of angular have changed.

Comment: @aet my question is: 1) if it is called periodically why outside of angular it is necessary? it will be evaluated anyway. 2) why $apply is called automatically after a lot of events such as ng-click? see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902379/why-do-we-need-ng-click)

Comment: Ah, ok, the answer is that the scope is not marked as dirty by things that happen "outside" of angular - and so it is not checked in the next digest cycle. ng-click/$scope.$apply() will mark that scope as dirty, and then that scope and its stuff will get checked.

Comment: @aet sorry for my ignorance but I read that $apply is actually calling $rootScope.$digest so how is it marking the scope as dirty and why calling $rootScope.$digest if it is already running periodically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51981/discussion-between-remi-and-aet)

Comment: I'd recommend to read the following article for better understanding the digest cycle in AngularJS: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the description of the digest cycle at http://blog.bguiz.com/post/60397801810/digest-cycles-in-single-page-apps that it is

> code that runs at an interval

is very misleading, and to be honest, when referring to Angular, I would even say wrong. To quote Pawel Kozlowski, [Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mZXjwz5X08EC&pg=PT547&lpg=PT547&dq=angularjs%20does%20not%20use%20any%20kind%20of%20polling%20mechanism%20to%20periodically%20check%20for%20model%20changes&source=bl&ots=T4H4PSXaST&sig=qR-usD2QqriowWkSNmkRC7EI1Rk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4Y1mU_uCDYPBO4LkgJAH&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=angularjs%20does%20not%20use%20any%20kind%20of%20polling%20mechanism%20to%20periodically%20check%20for%20model%20changes&f=false)

> AngularJS does not use any kind of polling mechanism to periodically check for model changes

To prove there is no polling, if you have a template of

```
<p>{{state}}</p>
```

and controller code of

```
$scope.state = 'Initial';
// Deliberately *not* using $timeout here
$window.setTimeout(function() {
  $scope.state = 'Changed';
},1000);
```

[as in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIfHYz9EYK14A5OS6NLd?p=preview), then the string shown to the user will remain as `Initial` and never change to `Changed`.

If you're wondering why you often see calls to `$apply`, but not always, it is probably because the various directives that come with Angular, such as `ngClick` or `ngChange` will call `$apply` themselves, which will then trigger the cycle. Event listeners to native JS events directly will not do this, so they will have to deliberately call `$apply` to have any changes made reflected in templates.

Answer (score 13):

The digest process is kicked-in when any of the following occur as part of angular context:

- DOM Events (like ng-click etc.)
- Ajax with callbacks ($http etc.)
- Timers with callbacks ($timeout etc.)
- calling $apply, $digest
- etc.

It is important to note that the normal browser related DOM events (onclick etc.) and setTimeout would not trigger a digest process as they work out of "Angular Context".

I learnt the above from the following:
[image: Angularjs Digest Cycle - TechCBT]

The above is a quick snapshot from a very in-depth tutorial available here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYuc1oSjhgY

Comment: This answer better address the question

Answer (score 3):

Any AngularJS scope variable when handled from outside (including ajax) needs a $apply().

`setTimeout` is Javascript function So `$apply` is needed to update angularjs values.

`$timeout` is a angularjs function which returns promise and  takes care of the current scope and runs in the same digest cycle.

So need not of `$apply()` function to update values.