# When does the digest get triggered in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, digest

All:

I got a question about how angularjs data digest monitor the changing of scope data, for example:

```
 <button ng-click="changename()">{{name}}</button>
```

And the data change function is like:

```
            $scope.name = "Change Name";
            $scope.changename = function(){
                $scope.name = "name1";
                $scope.name = "name2";
            }

            $scope.$watch("name", function(newname, oldname){
                if(newname!=oldname){
                    console.log("new: "+newname, "old: "+oldname);
                }
            });
```

This changename function change scope.name twice in a row, but the watcher can **only catch the change from "Change Name" to "name2"** ( the console only print "new: name2 old: Change Name")

Could anyone **confirm my guess** that the digest cycle only start after a function block finish executing?

Thanks

Comment: For future readers, you can check out the answers here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460025/when-digest-cycle-is-called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to correct the answer from `rbaghbanli` which is misleading.

Indeed, because JavaScript is single threaded, what happen when you click on that button is:

```
The variable `$scope.name` is set to "name1";
The variable `$scope.name` is set to "name2";
> end of execution stack

Angular runs a $digest cycle
The $watchers are executed
since a watcher value has changed, angular runs another $digest cycle
The $watchers are executed
The watcher have the same value, end of $digest cycle
> end of execution stack
```

So basically no watcher nor anything will happen when you are within the same function, until the end of every line of this function.

The reason why Angular runs a digest cycle after your `changename` call is because it is within a `ng-click` directive, and as with all Angular built-in directive, the code is actually wrapped inside a `$scope.$apply` call. You could read the `ng-click` as the following code (even if technically it is not exactly like this):

```
element.on('click', function() {
  $scope.changename();
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Note: I wanted to simplify the generic idea, but to be technically true, Angular executes its $digest cycle right after your code (as you can see in my pseudo `ng-click`), *within the same execution stack*. Which means any `setTimeout` or other asynchronous call will happen *after* the digest cycle and after the DOM has been updated with the latest changes, which can be useful sometimes.

Comment: Yes, your guess was right, and that is not so specific to AngularJS but a Javascript thing. Typically, if you want to execute a code *after* the current "execution stack", we use `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks, could you help with another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243804/why-ng-repeat-report-10-digest-iterations-reached

Comment: The only change I'd suggest to this is regarding the simplified version, that it's really more like `try { $scope.changename(); } finally { $rootScope.$digest(); }` . You'll get your `$digest` even if there are errors in the function.

Comment: Right @DRobinson, but I prefer to keep is the simplest for this specific question, and people would find a better explanation elsewhere if they wonder what is a digest cycle or what is the difference between `scope.$digest` and `scope.$apply`. But thanks for the precision

Comment: Sure, hence me adding a comment rather than editing your answer. I didn't see a need for your answer to change, but wanted it in the comments in case anybody got the crazy idea of "well if I force it to fail..."

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. JavaScript is executed on single thread, so there will be 2 invocation of $watch function, but only after `$scope.changename()` completes, so 2nd invocation will have `newname == oldname == 'name2'`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Angular triggers a digest cycle *after* some event has taken place. In your case, the `ngClick` directive triggers a digest after the provided expression is executed. The same is true for a number of other user-triggered events, e.g. `mouseover`, `keydown`, `keypress`.

So it doesn't matter how many times you change `name` inside `changename()`; the next digest cycle will only "see" the last value assigned.

Comment: Thanks, the key answer I am looking for is when the digest starts, so according to yours, it starts after the ng-click function finished and basically, you confirm my guess,  right?

Comment: @Kuan In this particular case, yes. But you don't have to guess this stuff. When in doubt, check Angular's source code. I just did that in order to answer your question. :)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I am pretty entry level. So I guess I am not that into reading source.