# Angular controller value and model values differ

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I want to do a simple comparison of 2 emails.

I'm curious about how data syncs between the Controller and the models.
I attached a screenshot where you can the the difference in the outputs and the actual view/model values.

[image: Difference between the controller values and model values]

`ng-keydown="equal(newNote.email)"` is used on the input field.

- What is the reason for this behaviour?
- Is there some kind of pending $digest cycle going on under the hood of Angular?
- How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: would be good to see how you are logging the values...

Comment: @eesdil I was logging the values with `ng-keydown="equal(newNote.email)"` on the confirmEmail input field. Thus calling the equal fn.
But I figured out that changing **ngKeydown** to **ngKeyup** fixes the issue.

Comment: Magic :) good to hear.

Comment: @eesdil It is magic indeed. Still I would like some Angular Guru to point out what is the actual reason for keydown not working. Because this I assume tells a lot about the Angular logic. :/

Comment: should check it, but I suppose during keydown, the value is not 'digested' yet.

Comment: @eesdil Seems like it.

Comment: This SO answer might shed some light on the digest cycle and event handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34519430/630544

Answer (score 0):

I think you are printing (console.log) values on change event and it prints old value.

You can use a watcher to compare values

```
$scope.watch('$scope.email2', function(oldval, newval){
        if ($scope.email1 == newval){
              dosomething();
        }
});
```

Or you can use ng-keyup like this

```
<input type='text' ng-model='email2' ng-keyup='validate_email()' />
```

and in controller

```
$scope.validate_email = function(){
    if ($scope.email1 == newval){
         dosomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed gave me the correct result in the log, but in a strange manner – only after 2 times changing the value of the field. What I mean is that the watcher was called after 2 digest cycles I assume. :)

Comment: Well, yes, this works, as I found out myself in the comments above. However, to accept this as an answer I would like to know the behind-the-scenes process of why exactly this works. :)

Comment: keyup works becuase at that time model has changed and that function was called after value has been changed and model has been updated that's why it works. but when you call it ng-keydown or ng-change, it's start of the change and it has not yet completed. It just says that something is going to happen but model has not been changed untill validation or console.log is executed. I think it's very simple to understand.

Comment: It is simple. I was just hoping that I would receive a pro tip on the topic. 
Still, would be nice if you refactor your controller code so it uses not a generic variable, but a $scope.email2 because the $watch fn is no longer used in your 2nd example.