# ng-if executes method continuously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
data-ng-if="(fooCtrl.displayControl(1))
```

`displayControl` method return a `true` or `false`.

What I found is that`ngif` is constantly listening for this even after it has been evaluated once. How I found this, was by pointing a break point on the method. After a few F8(in debugger), it will continue as normal.

Why is `ngif` is executing the method continuously?

Comment: `ngIf` is evaluated each `$digest` cycle. Depending how big that method is - it could bog down the site.

Comment: `data-ng-if=":: fooCtrl.displayControl(1)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your built-in directives will be triggered in every `$digest` cycle, see more about angular digest cycle [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460025/when-digest-cycle-is-called)

so be aware of using directives like `ng-show` or `ng-if` and don't make them listen on a function that does a lot of processing or function that have some loops and that kind of stuff, keep them listening on already determined booleans or simple functions

Answer (score 4):

Angular runs each watcher function on each digest cycle, so this is normal that your function gets checked multiple times. If you don't want this behaviour you can consider [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) (Angular 1.3.x).

```
data-ng-if=":: fooCtrl.displayControl(1)"
```

Comment: plus1 for one time binding info, thanks for your input!