# AngularJS: Is it possible to get $digest loop initiator?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I just placed this code in my App `run`

```
$rootScope.$watch((...args) => console.log('digest', args));
```

And it is seems that something calls $digest all the time. Never ending $digest cycle. All is working just fine, but is it ok?

I've checked all my `$interval` and `$timeout` usings, and it's seems that it's not the source of problem. Any way to know what called `$digest`?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460025/when-digest-cycle-is-called

Comment: It's very unclear. There is diffrent links in this answer, which tells different things. I looked at the angularJS source and wasn't able to find any periodic $digest calls. As I get it, $digest should be called automatically after using $http, $timeout e.t.c., but not periodically.

Comment: i.e. set breakpoint in $digest method and see callstack

Comment: Which Library's are you using. Maybe it's one of them

Comment: @PetrAveryanov , - good point