# Dynamically updating array ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and I have built some controller with angular which is shown in below.

```
var app = angular.module('jobs', []);
app.controller('DaCtrl',function(){
    this.itemlist = [{id:"001"},{id:"002"},{id:"003"}];
});
```

What I need is to update "itemlist" property dynamically by calling a function and display the items using ng-repeat
I tried like this and it didnt work :(

**What I have tried so far**
[JSFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/pprkng7o/8/)

[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/pprkng7o/14/)

Comment: You didn't call the function `addItems`...

Comment: I am calling that function through some other function I didn't mention it in the fiddle. Though I called to the addItems function it didn't work.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/pprkng7o/4/

Comment: worked for me too just adding the function, your problem is beyond the scope of the example

Comment: @elclanrs yes it's working in the page load but when call it again with some other dataset it won't work.Can you check the updated fiddle. (I have updated the fiddle)

Comment: how are you calling it? shouldn't you be using $scope as well?

Comment: @aw04, Yes true I am not using $scope, is there anyway to do what I wanted ?

Comment: even with the updated fiddle, you're never calling the addItems function... not sure i see what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you paste the full code?

Comment: aw04 Can u see I am calling ajax() function and getting the object and then assigning it to the "itemlist"

Comment: yep i see that, but you're calling the ajax() function from within the addItems() function... which never gets called

Comment: Though you call it , It's only working in page loads. When I call the "addItems" function again, the DOM is not updating.

Comment: @slicedtoad when I call that function with different dataset again after some time pagge loaded. DOM doesn't update.

Comment: oh, ok. this fiddle shows the actual problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pprkng7o/12/

Comment: it doesn't seem as though your fiddle example matches the problem which is why everyone keeps telling you the same thing... can you update your example please?

Comment: @slicedtoad exactly that's problem. I ll update my question with your fiddle.

Comment: Ok, I don't know anything about angular and its making my head hurt trying instantly understand the concepts... But this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475601/ng-repeat-list-in-angular-is-not-updated-when-a-model-element-is-spliced-from-th

Comment: @slicedtoad it's possible $scope.$apply could be needed, depends on how exactly it's getting the data... i can get this example to work though, and there are simpler issues. for example in the function itemlist (the one bound to the ui) is never updated so it makes sense that it only works initially

Comment: @aw04 Can you get the fiddle working ?

Comment: You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/pprkng7o/26/. I have changed your onclick event using ng-click and assign the function addItems to $rootScope. On the controller, you can use $watch to watch for the changes in the listObj.

Comment: @themyth92  can I call the "addItems()" function from the script ? not with "ng-click" ?

Comment: Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/pprkng7o/27/. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902379/why-do-we-need-ng-click#answer-20274848

Comment: @themyth92 Well,that was a life saver.I did some modification and now can call the "addItems" function from anywhere(Even from the console) .Thanks every one.

 Here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/pprkng7o/28/

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! It looks like you need to set the itemsList to the `$scope` variable, so it'll be available in your template.

Since you're a beginner, I recommend just putting everything on your `$scope` variable so you know they are accessible in the template and in your javascript, no matter what.

Here's the jsfiddle with a working solution (everything on `$scope`): http://jsfiddle.net/pprkng7o/25/

Comment: Can I call the function from out side I mean out side of the controller ? like "addItems()" without the button the click ?